# Tiled map not rendered fully

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.17. When I run a Follow action on a sprite, the tiled map can't render fully. The map looks exactly the same as the screen record shows in posts below

https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/1-5b2-tiled-map-not-rendered-fully/36661

https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/solved-tilemap-rotation-clipping/37114

But they were using Cocos Creator and can fix it by setting ENABLE_TILEDMAP_CULLING = false.

Is there any equivalent settings in C++ api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the root cause is that the Scene has been moved by Follow action. It seems in cocos2d-x, Scene is not supposed to move.